# gulp: find out file's directory name and put it into file

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-replace

I target multiple files with filename 'wp-config.php' that rest in

```
    source/some_site/wp-config.php
    source/another_site/wp-config.php
    source/and_the_other_one/wp-config.php
    ...
    source/and_more_and_more/wp-config.php
```

with `gulp.src(['source/**/wp-config.php'])`.

Can I find out in gulp the file's directory name?

It that happens to be the name of the site in my case. I'd like to update `define('DB_NAME', 'site_s_name');` in every `wp-config.php` with the name of the actual site. But current code only puts `define('DB_NAME', 'site1');` in every config:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

var db_name = 'site1';

gulp.task('update-config', function(){

  var regexp1 = /'DB_NAME', '.*'/;
  var subst1 = "'DB_NAME', '"+db_name+"'";

  gulp.src(['source/**/wp-config.php'])
  .pipe(replace(regexp1, subst1))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('destination'));
});
```

Or do I want too much from gulp? If solving this needs skills in node.js, then, unfortunately, I have zero of it.

Comment: Maybe you could use gulp-shell (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) with a sed command